# Why is my API call making multiple returns

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary, object

I'm making a simple app to track the International Space Station as a beginners project. I'm calling an API, and on the browser I am seeing multiple lines returned instead of just the one I want (latitude and longitude).

Here is the API I am using:

```
{
  message: "success",
  timestamp: 1612832513,
  iss_position: {
    longitude: "-112.2064",
    latitude: "35.1744"
  }
}
```

Here is the section of code where I think the issue is:

```
render() {
  var { items, isLoaded } = this.state;
  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; 
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul> 
          {Object.values(items).map(item => (
          <li key={item}> 
            <span >Latitude: {item.latitude} </span>
            <span >Longitude: {item.longitude} </span>
          </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div> 
    )
  };
};
```

Here is what I am seeing in the browser:

```
Latitude: Longitude:
Latitude: Longitude:
Latitude: -45.0969 Longitude: -32.9972
```

I think the issue is with `.map()`, but am not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Also if I left out any info that I should have included, let me know and I'll update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Object.values(items).map(item => ...)` the callback is called with:

- `item = items.message`
- `item = items.timestamp`
- `item = items.iss_position`

so in your JSX, `item.latitude` and `item.longitude` are actually attempting to read all the following values:

- `items.message.latitude`, `items.message.longitude`
- `items.timestamp.latitude`, `items.timestamp.longitude`
- `items.iss_position.latitude`, `items.iss_position.longitude`

Since there's only one pair of coordinates in the object, just write your JSX like this:

```
const { latitude, longitude } = items.iss_position;

return (
  <div>
    <span>Latitude: {latitude}</span>
    <span>Longitude: {longitude}</span>
  </div>
);
```

#### References

- [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/map)

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you for the help, and for explaining it so well.

Comment: @Tam `items` isn't an array it's an object.

Comment: @Tam you seem to be misunderstanding my point, you're [accessing properties that don't exist](https://tio.run/##XY5NCoMwEEb3nmJwpWCliT8tir1Cj1DSGCSiRjqjG8nZ0yi0hS7nPXjf9GIVKF96ptNkWuWcNBMSaFIjQgNbADAqRNGpCkJcpPRHmHhK2nMS41wBKxm/Zrxg2S404mM2qEmbqToCAIOZOk1Lu0dOjPGUn8v8yHgn6KOyImWXPA89t4Gtg@D@7JWkdBXDojA6norTUcxRtP3vfDvJbw0s2BiaG2w2rp17Aw).